# Do I have to load the scorm package in the frontend or have to unpack it in the backend and serve assets individually?

Tags: database, client-server, scorm

I am having a hard time understanding the final piece of the puzzle in implementing the SCORM playback and hosting(term hosting is similar to how static files are hosted to S3) in the e-learning platform that I am currently working on. So my problem is I do not know how I should interact with the SCORM package. From my understading, I need to host it in S3 then the client will load the SCORM package from S3 then read the imsmanifest to read the sequence of assets in the folders of the SCORM package. Also, I will need to provide the SCORM runtime environment for our lms.

So is loading the whole SCORM package in the frontend right or I will have to unpack the contents of it and have it load on every request of the client e.g. moving through the sequences of assets of the SCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to consult to a SCORM expert about this and the basic architecture that I am going for is, storing the SCORM package to a static file server e.g. S3 then it will serve as the delivery service for our LMS. Then for the client side, I will just the frontend to the bucket that contains the imsmanifest of the SCORM package and have the SCO loaded into the browser.

Comment: Hi @bexanderDbex, I understand that you have hosted all your SCORM files in the S3 bucket as static. What if someone wants to keep all the SCORM files private and load them into the frontend. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @justAnAnotherCoder I am not sure if I understand your question properly but if you want to "secure" the SCORM files here is what I would do:
1. Don't allow the client to directly interact with the files, rather have your client obtain a signed URL from the backend and make the client fetch from that link.
2. The headers should be set to "no-cache" to preven the browser from saving the files locally.

Comment: That means my workflow would be: 1) Upload the SCORM zip file into the S3 bucket and then uncompressed it. 2) Find the `.html` file inside the SCORM folder and generate the signed URL 3) Use iframe to run the run that `html` file. 4) I use simpleAPI to capture course info. 
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @bexanderDbex however, a signed URL can be generated on file level, not the folder level. If we generate a signed URL for a SCORM HTML file then the other files won't be accessible.

Comment: Is there any way we can natively host our SCORM file into a bucket then read the imsmanifest.xml file to get the launch file? I have uploaded a decompressed SCORM file in a bucket as public so that I can access the SCORM HTML file in the iframe. Unfortunately, when iframe trying to run the HTML file I am getting some wired error message like "unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play properly".